# Compute the changes in the x and y positions of moving dots

Tags: matlab, animation, trigonometry

I am trying to learn how to animate dots and update their x and y positions from frame to frame. I have found a tutorial online, and I am really struggling with the formulas that are used in dx and dy:

```
dots.speed = 3;                 %degrees/second
dots.duration = 5;              %seconds
dots.direction_deg = 30;        %degrees (clockwise from straight up)
dots.direction_rad = dots.direction_deg * pi /180 %direction converted to radians

% Calculate the distance travelled by a dot (in degrees), which is the speed (degrees/second) divided by the frame rate (frames/second).

dx = dots.speed*sin(dots.direction_rad)/display.frameRate;
dy = -dots.speed*cos(dots.direction_rad)/display.frameRate;
```

With my knowledge in trigonometry, I end up with these formulas for dx and dy:

Cos(angle) = Adjacent/Hypotenuse --> cos(dots.direction_rad) = 1/dx (1 is the distance from the origin to a point on the circle,which is equal to 1 radian).  --> dx = 1/cos(dots.direction_rad) --> the distance is then equal to :

```
dots.speed*1/cos(dots.direction_rad)*display.frameRate
```

Sin(angle) = Opposite/Hypotenuse --> sin(dots.direction_rad) = dy/1 --> the distance is then equal to :

```
dots.speed * sin(dots.direction_rad) / display.frameRate.
```

My formulas are not giving the expected result. So what I am doing wrong. I don't seem to understand how the dx and dy were computed in the tutorial. Please help! thanks

Comment: So your dots are supposed to move around a circle of radius = 1 at a speed of 3deg/ second ? What is the purpose of `direction_deg` ? Can you provide a minimal example and the link to the tutorial.

Comment: The aperture of the dot is not a circle but a rectangle. Following the logic of the code I found online, to compute the positions of the dots, we have to imagine that they are moving in a circle (http://www.mbfys.ru.nl/~robvdw/DGCN22/PRACTICUM_2011/LABS_2011/ALTERNATIVE_LABS/Lesson_2.html)

Comment: direction_deg is the angular distance of the dot in degrees.

Comment: So you can add `dx` and `dy` to the dots coordinates after each iteration. Something like `x = x+dx` and `y = y+dy`. Of course you have to define the initial position for `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I displayed only part of the code with the cos and sin formulas because I would like to understand why he defined dx with a 'sin' and dy with a '-cos'. I am rather struggling with the formulas.

Comment: Because `dx` and `dy` are a derivative. The derivative of cos(x) is -sin(x) and the derivative of sin(x) is cos(x). Ok ? But know you can ask why it's dx = sin(x) and not -sin(x). Because the direction is given clockwise but a trigonometric circle is always define counterclockwise. So since sin(-x) = -sin(x) the tutorial use -sin(-x) = sin(x).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195062/discussion-between-obchardon-and-kathia).